# Probability Deck of Cards

Tags: probability, combinatorics, card-games

In a hand of 13 playing cards from a deck of 52 whats the probability of drawing exactly one king.

My approach would be $${4 \choose 1}*{48 \choose 12}/{52 \choose 13}*{2}$$

I divided by 2 because I felt I had ordered the king and the other 12 cards chosen but this is wrong. Can someone please explain in depth why this is wrong so that I don't make the same mistake again.

Comment: The function $ {n \choose k} $ doesn't tell you anything about the order of choice. You choose $ k $ from $ n $ **at once**.

Comment: My problem is that I have picked the kings before the others when I could also have picked the kings afterwards

Comment: To get hold of this and train your intuition think of similar problems using smaller numbers (making it possible to count).

Comment: You could have - it wouldn't have mattered though, since multiplication is commutative

Answer (score 1):

you have two disjoints subsets: 'kings' and 'everything else'. $\binom{4}{1}\binom{48}{12}$ simply means 'any 1 out of 4' AND 'any 12 out of 48'. There's no order involved. Any form of order would be if, for example, you would need to get 3 kings. Then you would need to divide by $3!$ because the order doesn't matter.

Does this answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

The total number of ways to choose $13$ out of $52$ cards is:

$$\binom{52}{13}$$

---

The number of ways to choose $13$ out of $52$ cards with exactly $1$ king is:

$$\binom{4}{1}\cdot\binom{52-4}{13-1}$$

---

Hence the probability of choosing $13$ out of $52$ cards with exactly $1$ king is:

$$\frac{\binom{4}{1}\cdot\binom{52-4}{13-1}}{\binom{52}{13}}\approx43.88\%$$